# run command promt application from code C#

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
var startupPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName; // +\\Common

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments ="/c " + startupPath + @"\Common\sound 1.wav result.wav -tempo=35";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

Pathes are correct. A wanna to start application and set this parameters `sound 1.wav result.wav -tempo=35`. What am I doing wrong?
content of startInfo.Arguments:

```
"/c C:\\SOUNDS\\New folder\\TrunscribeHelper\\Common\\sound 1.wav result.wav -tempo=35"
```

I've tryed to start it directly:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(startupPath + @"\Common", "\\", "sound.exe"));
            startInfo.Arguments = "1.wav result.wav -tempo=35";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But Am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Can you show us what the contents of `startInfo.Arguments` is?

Comment: You might start out by not making it hidden, which would give you some potential clues as to the error.

Comment: maybe you should make a breakpoints and see what startupPath + @"\Common\sound" actually ends up being, and check to make sure that `sound.exe` is actually in the Common directory

Comment: Why do you start the command prompt at all? why not start the `sound` process directly?

Comment: Scott, check my code plz.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing this line:

```
startInfo.Arguments ="/c " + startupPath + @"\Common\sound 1.wav result.wav -tempo=35";
```

to

```
startInfo.Arguments ="/c \"" + startupPath + @"\Common\sound"" 1.wav result.wav -tempo=35";
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, someone edited my answer incorrectly. I've edited it back. Could you try it again please.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to set your path in the args under double quotes:

```
"/c \"C:\\SOUNDS\\New folder\\TrunscribeHelper\\Common\\sound 1.wav\" result.wav -tempo=35"
```